# google cloud function can't be called from postman where unauthenticated is allowed

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, postman

I have the following simple google cloud function:

```
exports.recordInfo = functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) => {
      functions.logger.info({
        requestData: request.body.data
      })
      functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {
        structuredData: true
      });
      response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
    });
```

I can get it running in the emulator and obtain a local host link, where I can see the response in my browser. I'm unable to test sending request data from postman. The same link just hangs with no response. I've tried using request, request.body, and request.rawBody in both the emulator and the deployed function.

I'm trying to find a platform like postman to send a request containing an object such as:

```
{
      'data': {
        'objID': 'abc123',
        'objName': 'obj1',
        'objDescription': 'object'
      }
}
```

The ultimate goal is to record this object as a firestore document in the database, but right now I just want to be able to ensure that I can see and log the object in the cloud function.

The only response that I get when I view the function url is "Hello from Firebase". I am also seeing the "Hello logs!" statement in emulator logs, and in logs associated with the deployed function. I am not seeing the object with the 'structuredData' key in the deployed cloud function logs.

Comment: If the request is hanging, authentication is not involved. Edit the question showing the request and response. Another excellent tool to use is `curl` from the command line.

Comment: Please edit the question to describe in more detail what you're doing that doesn't work the way you expect.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can duplicate the problem and observe the same result.  I suggest reading this to help understand what's helpful in a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use a stack snippet for code that isn't runnable. Stack snippets are only meant for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that can be run on a browser. Please format your code using a [code block](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.

Comment: @JohnHanley I put what I know about the request and the response, I'm almost as new to coding as I am to stackoverflow.

Comment: I mean show how you are making the request and the results.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added to my question as much as I could figure out, if I can clarify further please let me know. Thanks for being patient!

Comment: @cherryblossom, thank you and I'm sorry! I fixed it! Have a great evening!

Comment: We still don't know how you're making the query - there is not enough information in your question that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the issue with a post request to the function URL with the provided data object in the body.

The issue is that you need to use CORS library in order to make the request body accessible, as shown in [this example onRequest function](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js), which is referenced in this [google documentation on HTTP requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).